# Not able to find export content in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created a web content using default *test* user in Liferay 6.2 GA2. I want to export that web content to the LAR file. When I go to Admin -> Content where all the web contents are listed, I am not able to see any export option on this page.

I do see export option in web content display portlet. Can anybody throw some light on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is icon at right top of page for exporting web-contents.

Comment: thanks I found it.Its there on top right corner with black rectangle which has text "Web content" written in white . There is one clickable link to the left of this text but its not visible.When I did mouse over randomly I saw my mouse pointer getting chnaged to indicate that is a link.Thanks again.